# How to write does not exist in PHP

Tags: php

So I have an if statement in PHP that looks like this:

```
if ($_GET['Squares'] != 0)
```

but really I need to check if the variable squares has been passed via the url. So it needs to be if squares doesn't exist. I tried the following but it throws errors.

```
if (!isset $_GET['Squares'])
```

Can anyone tell me what the correct syntax is please?

Comment: `if(!isset($_GET["Squares"]))`

Comment: use `if (!isset $_GET['Squares'])`

Comment: This question is like giving out reputation, so I am not going to upvote any of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add parentheses around the `isset()` call:

```
if (!isset($_GET['Squares']))
```

In PHP, all function calls have to have parentheses around the arguments. Be sure not to confuse language constructs as functions, such as `print` and `echo` which can be called without parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
if (isset($_GET['Squares'])) {
   // variable passed via the URL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!isset $_GET['Squares'])
          ^-----------------^--herr is the problem should be like below



if (!isset ($_GET['Squares']))
```

and use instead

```
if (isset($_GET['Squares'])) {
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add parentheses. `isset` is a function, all functions need their `()` around the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it this way

```
if(isset($_GET['Squares'])){
...
}
```

This will check if the variable has been set and if it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

`isset($variable)` function will help you to find whether `$variable` is set or not.

So to check whether `Squares` is set in URL or not, you can try something like this

```
if(isset($_GET['Squares'])){

//The Squares is set

}
```